# How to make wordpress default homepage

Tags: wordpress

Currently to access my wordpress homepage you need to enter www.mydomain.co.uk/site1 - how would I get my wordpress site to load when I type www.mydomain.co.uk?

This is the first website that I have ever made, the most simple explanation would be really helpful

Comment: it seems like you installed the site in the directory **site1** right ?

Comment: +Temani Afif yes I did

Comment: ok have a look to my answer then, hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do in this case is to migrate the domain of the site by keeping everything inside **site1**. You are not obliged to move all the files.

Here is the 2 steps you need to do :

1) take the index.php and .htaccess file from the folder site1 and copy them to your root folder (don't move them, but only copy them). Then open the index.php you copied and you will see this line :

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

replace it by

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/site1/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

2) Now go to the settings in dashboard of the site and you will see 2 urls : Wordpress Address and Site address. Change the Site Address and make it only **www.mydomain.co.uk** then save the changes.

Now you site should be served from root URL. In case of any issue, clear your cookies and cache. Also go to the permalinks settings and hit save again.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like all the files of your website is inside "site1" folder. So if you need a fresh URL like www.mydomain.co.uk. Then you need to transfer all the files and folders `(wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content, wp-config.php files etc.)` to the root folder.

And also needs to update `wp_options` DB  table with new value for  `siteurl` & `home`

Comment: this totally wrong ! doing this will break the whole site. There is the database that need to be updated with the new URL. without this the site will stop working and for someone without experience it will be difficult to make the site working again.